# Python Pandas event studies

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to conduct an event study in python pandas. I have 2 datasets, one that has a date and description of events, and another dataset that has the daily stock returns for stocks. What I want to get is a dataset that contains stock returns for 90 days before and after the event.

Data1 Ex:
StockID EventDate
A   1/1/2001
B   5/1/2002
C   10/1/2005
D   12/1/2006
... ...

Data2 Ex:
StockID Date    Returns
A   1/1/1996    0.01
A   1/2/1996    0.01
A   1/3/1996    0.02
... ... ...
A   12/20/2010  0.02
B   1/1/1996    0.01
... ... ...
Z   1/1/1996    0.05

Wanted dataset Ex:
StockID EventDate   Returns Event
... ... ... ...
A   12/31/2000  0.01    -1
A   1/1/2001    0.02    0
A   1/2/2001    0.01    1
... ... ... ...
B   4/30/2002   0.01    -1
B   5/1/2002    0.02    0
B   5/2/2002    0.01    1
... ... ... ...
C   10/1/2005   0.02    0
..  ..  ..  ..

I've tried to lead/lag the variables on Data2 to create 180 new variables and merge it to Data1, but that was very inefficient and lead to memory issues(used over 100GB of RAM) since Data2 is somewhat large.

Here's what I tried:

```
hshifts = range(1, 91)
for hshift in hshifts:
    colname = 'RETN%d' % hshift
    data2[colname] = data2.groupby('StockID')['RET'].shift(hshift)
for hshift in hshifts:
    colname = 'RETP%d' % hshift
    data2[colname] = data2.groupby('StockID')['RET'].shift(-hshift)

wanted_dataset = pd.merge(data1, data2, on='Date')
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty inefficient.  You're shifting a whole column 90 times per event!  I would try a more SQL type of approach.  Select the 90 dates before and after each event for each stock.  Merge those and things are already pre-shifted for you.  That should be much more efficient.